# First time beta release, with no production release

Tags: android, google-play, store

I have an app that's about to go to go to production on 1st July. I've decided to push a beta release to the store today - 11th June, so that I don't have to wait for a long review period later.

1. If I push to beta, will the app be available to everyone? Because this link says that Beta will only be available to people who have the public app installed, and my app is not on production yet, so people without the download link wouldn't have downloaded it yet. [Link](http://%20https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180)

   [image: Beta release description]

---

2. If I push an alpha release, will there be a review period, when I push that same alpha build to production?

Answer (score 0):

For apps that haven't been published to production i.e. early access apps, Users can find your app open test via search on Google Play. Once users find your listing, they can install your app normally.

But make sure you store listing ,content rating, distrbution settings are ready for Google Play Store listing.

You can find more detail here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

For your second question, Yes there will be review period but the process will take less than usual.